# Ввод текста в canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Без градиента текст выводится, но с градиентом его нет, не могу понять почему. И ещё, как можно сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам выбирал цвет текста?

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width='600px'></canvas>
<input type="text" id="text"></input>
<button onclick="func();"> Ввод</button>
<input type="color" id="color">
<script>
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 5, 150, 220);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "purple");
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);

  function func() {
    var e = document.getElementById("text"),
      t = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      n = t.getContext("2d");
    n.textBaseline = "top";
    n.fillText(e.value, 150, 0);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли указать цвет для текста.

Берем цвет из вашего поля ввода цвета, как:

```
  colorText = document.getElementById("color"),
```

и перед "отрисовкой" текста указываем:

```
n.fillStyle = colorText.value;
```

Более подробно об [fillStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle)

Ваш пример:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 5, 150, 220);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "purple");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);

function func() {
  var e = document.getElementById("text"),
    t = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    colorText = document.getElementById("color"),
    n = t.getContext("2d");
  n.textBaseline = "top";
  n.font = "30px serif";
  n.fillStyle = colorText.value;
  n.fillText(e.value, 50, 0);
}

func();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width='600px'></canvas>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="text" value="TestText"></input>
<button onclick="func();"> Ввод</button>
<input type="color" id="color">
```